# Extract power levels of mp3 sound at given times?

Tags: data, sound

Consider loading an `mp3` audio file

```
mymp3=Import["test.mp3"];
```

Now we get an object that looks like

[image]

One can see a picture of the sound fluctuations, which means that Mathematica knows how to access the raw values of the wave. Now, I would like to take small bits of the waveform at certain times (let's say, from second `40.0` to second `40.3`), sum up its absolute value squared and divide by the time length to get the power of the signal at this time. Can I do this in Mathematica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 11.1, you can use [`AudioLoudness`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AudioLoudness.html).  It can use several loudness definitions.  I am not familiar with these, but you can look them up.

```
au = ExampleData[{"Audio", "Clapping"}]

AudioLoudness[au] // ListLinePlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

To compute precisely what you are describing in version 11.0 or later, use [`AudioBlockMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AudioBlockMap.html).

```
AudioBlockMap[Norm, au, Quantity[0.1, "Seconds"]] // ListLinePlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

To get the plot you showed in your screenshot, use `AudioPlot[au]`.

Comment: This looks good, but what if I want to end up with a table of loudness? Each entry in the table should correspond to the average loudness within `0.3` consecutive seconds in the `mp3` audio.

Comment: @Kagaratsch You get a TimeSeries from these functions, you can convert it with `Normal`. `Normal@AudioBlockMap[Norm, au, Quantity[0.3, "Seconds"]]`.

Comment: The waveform is stored in the second argument of a `RawData` object, which is in the first argument of the `Audio` object we get upon `Import` of the file. I wanted to access these by taking parts of the `Audio` object, or isolate the waveform by substitution rules, but nothing seems to work. It is as if the head `Audio` is protected against any manipulations. Just out of curiosity, is there a way to extract the `List` with raw waveform information from the `Audio` object somehow?

Comment: @Kagaratsch `Audio` objects are atomic and their internal structure shouldn't be messed with. You can get the data with `AudioData`. It's an analogue of `ImageData`. Many other audio functions are named similarly to image processing ones. You can also do direct arithmetic on `Audio` objects without extracting their contents, like `Total[#^2] & /@ AudioPartition[au, 0.3]`

Comment: @Kagaratsch Except of course `Norm` is not `Total[#^2]&` but `Sqrt@Total[#^2]&`.  I made a mistake there.

Comment: I think the definition of power is along the lines of `((Total[#^2])/Length[#])&` (up to normalization), but I'll use the built in functions you pointed to, in hopes that they are more efficient.

Comment: @Kagaratsch, then that would just be `RootMeanSquare[#]^2 &`.

Comment: I wonder, is there a way to take the `AudioBlockMap` of a sound not based on `Quantity[x, "Seconds"]` bits but based on cutting the whole sound into `n` equally long parts? I am experiencing some rounding errors with the time intervals, which make it hard to prevent padding.